# optionally prompt user with menu based on argument

Tags: bash

How can I change below script as follows:

1. If a number is passed as argument (**do not prompt user**), do not show option menu, check it matches one of options, and if so, continue with that option
2. If the number is not passed (**prompt user**), show bash option menu

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You could extract the handling of options to a function:

```
handleOption() {
    local opt=$1
    case "$opt" in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            return 1
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
}
```

And the menu to another function:

```
menu() {
    local PS3='Please enter your choice: '
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        handleOption "$opt" || break
    done
}
```

And then implement validation of the first command line argument:

- Is it an integer?
- If it's an integer, is it within the range `1..${#options[@]}` ?
- If both the above are true, then call the `handleOption` directly with the appropriate value from the `options` array

Something like this:

```
arg=$1
if [[ $arg =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && (( 1 <= arg )) && (( arg <= ${#options[@]} )); then
    opt=${options[arg - 1]}
    handleOption "$opt"
elif [ "$arg" ]; then
    echo "warning: invalid option: $arg"
    menu
else
    menu
fi
```

Comment: Good one!  Even if that was a home-work question, they still have to put in some work...

Comment: @Fabby you think it's a homework question? Ouch then, I said too much :-/

Comment: Smells like it, but teachers have Internet too, you know...  **>:-)**